# Where can i find php-pgsql package for RedHat 7?

Tags: php, postgresql, redhat, php-pgsql

I am developing my project with

- PHP 5.6.27
- PostgreSQL 9.6.1
- RedHat 7 OS

I had searched for the php_pgsql package everywhere. 
also tried with some rpms. but still I am not able to get the package.

I developed my whole project in php_pgsql package in windows and i faced this issue when tried to shift from Windows to Linux. 
please help to solve this. thank you.

Comment: This seems more like a server configuration question than a programming question. You could try posting it on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) instead.

Comment: [php5-pgsql](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=php5-pgsql)

Comment: @AdrienLeber : will you answer me with more details?

Comment: The package name is `php5-pgsql`. So, to install it, I suppose something like this : `yum install php5-pgsql`

Comment: when i try  this.. this is the result -No package php5-pgsql available.

Comment: And welcome on open-source OS. = )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127941/discussion-between-adrien-leber-and-telen-stanley).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to install that package, you'll need to remove the excluding rule for php in `/etc/yum.conf`.

Then install the package :

```
yum update
yum install php-pgsql
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not help me, the official link did

1. Install CentOS SCLo RH repository:

   `sudo yum install centos-release-scl-rh`
2. Install rh-php72-php-common rpm package:

   `sudo yum install rh-php72-php-common`

Reference: https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-sclo-rh-x86_64/rh-php72-php-common-7.2.24-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html#download